# How to use in-memory tables in Tableau?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, tableau-api

I want to access in-memory data from Spark SQL in Tableau.

I read this tutorial and did the following:
http://downloads.tableau.com/beta/Tableau%20Spark%20SQL%20Setup%20Instructions.pdf

On Linux in VirtualBox:

- Downloaded SparkSQL 1.5.2 with Hadoop 2.6 from http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/spark/spark-1.6.0/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz
- runs start-master.sh and start-slaves.sh
- runs this command:

  start-thriftserver.sh --master spark://localhost:7077 --
  driver-class-path $CLASSPATH --hiveconf hive.server2.thrift.bind.host localhost --hiveconf hive.server2.thrift.port 10001

On host site (Windows 8):

- downloaded Tableau,
- forwarded ports (8124 on host = 10001 on guest)
- installed Spark ODBC Driver.

After that i successfully connected Tableau with SparkSQL.

Now i want to create some tables in spark-shell and access them using Tableau.
I run these commands on spark-shell:

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext.implicits._
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
val people = sc.textFile("examples/src/main/resources/people.txt").map(_.split(",")).map(p => Person(p(0), p(1).trim.toInt)).toDF()
people.registerTempTable("people")
```

After that i connected to Spark Thrift Server once again but still no data were visible. The problem is that:

- I don't know what to do to make 'people' table visible for Tableau.
- I don't know, what determines that data from Spark SQL is accessible for Tableau.

How to make this data visible for Tableau?

Comment: Should i use  HiveThriftServer2.startWithContext(sqlContext.asInsanceOf[HiveContext]) ? How to set host and port of HiveContext?

Comment: Using `SQLContext.setConf` method?

Answer (score 0):

You should simply register your table as permanent tables using `saveAsTable` or similar.

The following assumes Spark 2.0, but is similar to the other versions too.

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate
import spark.implicits._

case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

val people = spark.read
  .option("inferSchema", true)
  .csv("examples/src/main/resources/people.txt")
  .as[Person]
people.write.saveAsTable("people")
```

After the `saveAsTable` has finished, you should see `people` table from *any* client that can talk to the Hive metastore in use, Tableau including.

Comment: Hi Jacek. Reading tables from disk instead of in memory will obviously be slower. Is it true that there is no way to read temp tables from Tableau?